# How to intercept and possibly block process creation, system-wide?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, driver, wdk

I'm trying to make an [AppLocker](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424367.aspx)-like service that should intercept creation of processes based on certain restrictions set by an administrator.

*(For those who are wondering why I can't simply use Microsoft's AppLocker, the answer is that it is available only on the Server, Enterprise and Ultimate versions of Windows 7 and up.)*

So I did some research and found the [CreateProcessNotifyEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542860(v=vs.85).aspx) routine that can be called before each process is started/ended.

I don't have a big experience writing Windows Kernel drivers. And thus I'm curious if this is the correct approach to do what I described above? Or maybe there's just a user-mode WinAPI that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Looks like the right approach to me.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Thanks. Do you know of any way to make it work under Windows XP as well? (PS. I realize that it's a discontinued OS, but we still have many clients that run XP on their workstations.)

Comment: I *think* the traditional approach was to install a kernel-mode hook on NtCreateProcess.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Hmm. After your suggestion I found this article from 2005: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11985/Hooking-the-native-API-and-controlling-process-cre where the author claims that hooking `NtCreateProcess` is not a correct approach and instead hooks to `NtCreateSection`. The issue is that what he does to accomplish it seems like a "hack" to me, since he is doing a lot of x86 asm injections in the target API to hook to it, which will obviously not work under x64. Such approach may also be "flagged" by an installed AVP.

Comment: I found an older article that shows how to use `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine`, which works under XP but unfortunately will not allow to block process creation: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2018/Detecting-Windows-NT-2K-process-execution

Comment: @c00000fd I think hooking the NtCreateProcess can be done after ntoskrnl.exe has been loaded so you don't have to alter the file. You will need to make a driver to edit ntoskrnl exports via some ioctl. Not an easy task, but it should be possible.

Comment: @Pyjong: Do you guys know of any C sample that shows this _driver manipulation_. (Especially stuff that can run in post-XP era, and x64 OS.)

Comment: @c00000fd Specificaly for your purpose no. As for driver writing: this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9504/Driver-Development-Part-Introduction-to-Drivers is the best on CP I think, but beware driver writing is way harder than user space programming, don't expect you read an article and you can start with drivers right away. There are also several  books ca. 800 pages each :) . And as for PE hackery I would recommend starting with legendary Matt Pietrek's Peering inside portable executable https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx

Comment: Kernel hooking won't work on Vista or later, that's one of the reasons CreateProcessNotifyEx and various other routines were added, so that there would be other ways to do things that used to be done via hooking.  So I would expect you to use CreateProcessNotifyEx on Vista and later and hooking on 32-bit XP.  I'm not sure where 64-bit XP/2003 fits in.